# Equation of straight line with given points

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have Points **M1(-1,1)** and **M2(2,3)**. 
From applied formula:

```
y-y1=((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))*(x-x1)
```

Solving that gives:

`y-1=((3-1)/(3-(-1)))*(x-(-1))`,

which when solved becomes: `2x - 3y + 5 = 0`.

I cannot understand how I get that last result. Can you please explain

Comment: What don't you understand about it? Also, is this a *math* question, or a *Mathematica* question?

Comment: How I get this 2x - 3y + 5 = 0

Comment: `y-1=(3-1/2-(-1))*(x-(-1))` is incorrect, it should be `y - 1 == ((3 - 1)*(x - -1))/(2 - -1)`, the result follows directly.

Comment: @Feyre. Why is it incorrect? Directly plugging in the results gives `y - 1 == ((3- (-1)) / (2 - (-1)) * (x - (-1))` What you wrote and this are equivalent, no? Or am I really missing something in basic arithmetic. 

@TeodorKolev What exactly are you trying to achieve? Get a symbolic expression for the line? Or do you want the line to be function for later use? And what exactly don't you understand about the solved form? It's perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try

```
x1 = -1; y1 = 1; x2 = 2; y2 = 3;
Solve[y - y1 == ((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))*(x - x1), y]
```

which yields your mentioned solution:

```
(*{y -> 1/3 (5 + 2 x)}*)
```